# Indefinite integral of $\int \frac{5-4x}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}dx$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate $$\int \frac{5-4x}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}dx$$

I've tried u-substitution($u=x^2-3x+2$), but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work, so I've tried completing the square:

$$\:\int \frac{5-4x}{\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}}dx$$

But I'm still stuck on where to go from there. I'm guessing I need to use the $\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}$ formula, but I can't figure out what to do with $5-4x$.

Comment: Hint: write $$5-4x=l(2x-3)+m$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $5-4x=-1-4\left(x-\dfrac32\right)$

So, we have
$$-4\int\dfrac{\left(x-\dfrac32\right)dx}{\sqrt{\left(x-\dfrac32\right)^2-\left(\dfrac12\right)^2}}-\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(x-\dfrac32\right)^2-\left(\dfrac12\right)^2}}$$

For the first integral, set $\left(x-\dfrac32\right)^2-\left(\dfrac12\right)^2=u$

Answer (score 1):

Hint-
$5-4x=\alpha(2x-3)+\gamma$
You can find both $\alpha, \gamma$ by comparing terms on both sides and then express it in the form of the derivative and use the standard formula for the denominator.
$$\int\frac{-2(2x-3)-1}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}dx=-2\int \frac{2x-3}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}dx \ -\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Directly substitute $u^2=x^2-3x+2\implies (x-\dfrac32)\,dx=u\,du$.

Note that $(5-4x+1)-1=\color{blue}{(6-4x)}-1=\color{blue}{-4(x-\dfrac32)}-1.$ Now, you can separate the integral and use $\displaystyle\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}$ for the second half.